# Djongo library error when adding an object to database

Tags: python, django, mongodb, djongo

I am getting a djongo library error when I am trying to add an **Station** object in my admin panel. The error page says there is **no exception message supplied** so I am facing difficulty to pinpoint what is causing the error. The error is of **RecursionError**

```
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\tokens.py", line 19, in __contains__
    return item is not None and (self is item or item[:len(self)] == self)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

I asked chatgpt about the same and it suggested me to check my models.py file for any loops in relationship with other models but I did and I think my models.py file is not causing this, So can it be a bug on djongo's side?

**models.py**

```
from djongo import models

class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
class Station(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    # Add other station-related fields as needed
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Bus(models.Model):
    number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    # Add other bus-related fields as needed

    # Define a Many-to-Many relationship with Station
    stations = models.ManyToManyField(Station)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.number
```

**Full first traceback error**

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/bus/station/add/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 808, in __iter__
    yield from iter(self._query)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 167, in __iter__
    yield self._align_results(doc)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\query.py", line 269, in _align_results
    if selected.table == self.left_table:
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\sql_tokens.py", line 133, in table
    return alias2token[name].table
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\sql_tokens.py", line 133, in table
    return alias2token[name].table
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\sql_tokens.py", line 133, in table
    return alias2token[name].table
  [Previous line repeated 917 more times]
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\sql_tokens.py", line 130, in table
    name = self.given_table
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\djongo\sql2mongo\sql_tokens.py", line 141, in given_table
    name = self._token.get_real_name()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 361, in get_real_name
    return self._get_first_name(dot_idx)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 386, in _get_first_name
    return token.get_name()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 355, in get_name
    return self.get_alias() or self.get_real_name()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 344, in get_alias
    _, ws = self.token_next_by(t=T.Whitespace)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 244, in token_next_by
    return self._token_matching(funcs, idx, end)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 223, in _token_matching
    if func(token):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\sql.py", line 242, in <lambda>
    funcs = lambda tk: imt(tk, i, m, t)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\utils.py", line 100, in imt
    elif types and any(token.ttype in ttype for ttype in types):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\utils.py", line 100, in <genexpr>
    elif types and any(token.ttype in ttype for ttype in types):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Envs\routemaster\lib\site-packages\sqlparse\tokens.py", line 19, in __contains__
    return item is not None and (self is item or item[:len(self)] == self)
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison
```

**Note-** After removing the foreignkey relation in **Stations** the error is eliminated. But I want to use that feature so can someone fix it

Comment: This is not the actual error TBH as it's coming from tokens.py which resides in your virtual environment folder. I didn't find any error in your models.py. Can you provide more information on the error log?

Comment: I edited my question adding the first traceback call that might help

Comment: What version of django and djongo are you using? Also are you sure you didn't forget to migrate?

Comment: Django - 4.1.11
Djongo - 1.3.6

Yes I did apply migrations

Comment: The Djongo version you are using is really old and it shouldn't create any compatibility issues with your current version of Django. Therefore the problem is originating from somewhere else. As it is an `Internal server error` and `Recursion error`, your syntax is correct, but somewhere in code, something is referencing itself, hence the error. I want to ask you two questions.

1. What is this `routermaster`? Is it your environment name?
2. Are you getting any error while creating entry for City or Bus model through Admin site?

Comment: Yes routemaster is my env name and no I am not getting any error when creating entry for City or Bus model. It only happens when I try to create entry for Station. I am using City as foreign key in Station so something has to do with it

Comment: Okay, then I need to see the `admin.py` where you registered your models and `serializers.py` if any. Best to upload them to any drop site such codeshare or codefile and put the link here. Also if you can share the `settings.py`, that would be really helpful. For security, remove the `SECRET_KEY` (along with other secrets) from settings.py before sharing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to resolve this issue just switch to Django<=4.0.10,pymongo==3.12.3.
This will surely fix your issue.
After changing this you would be able to add data related to foreign key.